# Consumer Driven Contract Tests for C++ APIs

Tags: c++, api, testing, pact, contract

I am developing a static C++ library that has some Public APIs. 
I have to implement Consumer Driven Contract for the APIs that the library provides.
But in my case I have to provide the contract to the consumers on which they will agree upon.

The inspiration of implementing the Contract based testing came from PACT (https://docs.pact.io/). The contract in PACT is in form of JSON file and it is mainly based on REST and http responses.

If I have to implement the contract based testing for C++ APIs. Then what is the best approach. I could see boost has Design By Contract, but it is more like Assertions but there is no contract defined in a file like PACT. (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/contract/doc/html/index.html)

Is there any way that the contract can be defined in a file and all the APIs can be tested. The main purpose of this is to test in isolation.

Could you please share some inputs on to implement the contracts defined in a file and write a test program for these contracts.

Answer (score 2):

> I have to implement Consumer Driven Contract for the APIs that the library provides. 
>   But in my case I have to provide the contract to the consumers on which they will agree upon.

Those two statements aren't compatible with each other. Providing the contract *to* the consumer by its very nature can't be *consumer driven*.

In any case, if you'd like to ensure that a contract  is generated and verified by both parties, Pact currently doesn't support C++ - but that doesn't mean you can't use it.

See these links in order to test both the consumer and provider side using Pact tooling:

- Consumer - https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-mock_service/blob/master/script/example.sh
- Provider - https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/other_languages
- DIY Contracts in case Pact can't work for you - https://github.com/DiUS/diy-contract-example

If you are doing provider driven contracts and aren't interested to know if the consumer itself is compatible, you could consider using something like Swagger (OpenAPI Spec) to define the API and then use tools like Dredd to see if it matches.

Comment: The C++ APIs does not communicate through http or message Queues. They are just simple C++ public methods that will be called directly by the consumer. For example bool function1(const std::string & str, std::shared_ptr<xx::system> sys) . I guess pact is not suitable for APIs like this ans it is good for APIs that communicate though http

Comment: Yes, it is actually not Consumer driven and it is Provider driven. What am trying to achieve is testing in isolation, so that integration with other components (consumers) goes smoothly. For that I am trying to provide a contract document, which would say how the API responds to different kind of inputs, so that the consumer is clear on what to expect the API and the consumers can do testing based on the contract document.

Comment: You could also look at DIY contracts (e.g. https://github.com/DiUS/diy-contract-example)